# Can we apply video tags in a site that is HTML4 supported

Tags: html, video, jwplayer

I have a site that is having doctype html4 standard. We need to run videos of your site in ipad and we are willing to put in video tag into it to support video play into ipad. Do we need to change the doctype to html5 will it create problem in existing code. Like in css box model etc. We are supporting ie7 mozilla 3+ and chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to have the HTML5 doctype to use the video tag.
It will depend on the browser how it chooses to handle it.

For example, here's a page with the video element using HTML4 doctype
view-source:http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-html5/11895/single-mp4-video

However, it renders fine in my Firefox. Try it on your browser of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem as previous content will still work as expected. I say update the doctype

Comment: It has nothing to do with doctype, it depends only on browser support.